# How to check if the back button of the ActionBarSherlock was clicked?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using the library ActionBarSherlock, and put a item with the property `android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"`. How to check if the back button of the ActionBarSherlock was clicked? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to override

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:

    }
    return true;    
}
```

from the doc:

> his hook is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected.
>   The default implementation simply returns false to have the normal
>   processing happen (calling the item's Runnable or sending a message to
>   its Handler as appropriate). You can use this method for any items for
>   which you would like to do processing without those other facilities.

Answer (score 0):

the answer above works (Thanks). But for my code, this solution works best ...

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(
        com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

    item.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                            // running changes ...
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {

            //  running changes ...

            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
};
```